# Correct use of keys when joining tables in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-db-api

Currently learning data science with SQLite and Pandas. Working on a political contributions dataset. I'm wondering what is the purpose of `WHERE contributors.candidate_id = candidates.id` in the code below when joining two tables. Given my aim is to extract contributors for a particular candidate and include their name from another table, would the output not be the same without this condition?

```py
implicit_join_sel = """
SELECT
    contributors.last_name, contributors.first_name, contributors.amount, candidates.last_name
FROM
    contributors, candidates
WHERE
    contributors.candidate_id = candidates.id
AND candidates.last_name = 'Obama';
"""

db.cursor().execute(implicit_join_sel)
```

Output:

```html
contributors.last_name  contributors.first_name contributors.amount candidates.last_name
0   Buckler Steve   50.0    Obama
1   Buckler Steve   25.0    Obama
2   Buckheit    Bruce   100.0   Obama
3   Buckel  Linda   2300.0  Obama
4   Buckel  Linda   -2300.0 Obama
```

FYI summary of tables:

```html
--Candidates--
    id  first_name  last_name   middle_name party
0   33  Joseph  Biden   NaN D
1   36  Samuel  Brownback   NaN R

--Contributors--
    last_name   first_name  middle_name street_1    street_2    city    state   zip amount  date    candidate_id
0   Agee    Steven  NaN 549 Laurel Branch Road  NaN Floyd   VA  24091   500.0   2007-06-30  16
4   Akin    Charles NaN 10187 Sugar Creek Road  NaN Bentonville AR  72712   100.0   2007-06-16  16
```

Comment: What happens when you leave that condition out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sytax of the `FROM` clause, alone, would cause every row of the `contributors` table to be joined to every row of the `candidates` table.  The `WHERE` clause limits the join to only those pairs of rows with the same candidate ID.

The form of your `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses is not as clear as more modern SQL syntax, which would express this as

```
FROM
   contributors
   inner join candidates on contributors.candidate_id = candidates.id
```